# Take multiple input without declaring Variable for that input

Tags: java

```
public class INPUT{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1,num2;
        num1 = input.nextInt();
        num2 = input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

My question is how to take 2 inputes without declaring 2 variables.Suppose if i input  some int n=2.It will prompt two times two take my input.

Comment: an array?what do you do after taking inputs?

Comment: please post the code in the question body, and not as an image/link

Comment: not an array.I want to try different test cases so for that i need to know

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to declare an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-to-declare-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

```
    System.out.println("How many numbers?");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    Integer numbers[] = new Integer[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        numbers[i] = scanner.nextInt();
    }
```

First input is how many you want to have input and then you may store each input in array. In this way, you have a single variable : the array.
Here, it is an example. You could also exit the input with a special input, for example : `-1` .